# Richfaces 3.3.3.final Datatable Selection

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Can someone hint me on how to utilize `selection` functionality of `extendeddatatable` in  `rich:datatable` ?

My requirement is each row contains more than 15 columns and all are editable and should be able to scale upto 3000 records in a page.

I'm using JSF 1.2 and richfaces 3.3.3.final with spring webflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the selection attribute on extendeddatatable:

Declare in your view

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="xxxDataTable" value="#{xxxBean.listXxxDataModel}"   
var="xxxItem" selectionMode="single" rows="3" width="800px" height="100px" noDataLabel="#{msg.dataTable_noDataLabel}"
selection="#{xxxBean.xxxSelection}">
```

Bind your dataTable value to ExtendedTableDataModel : use a org.richfaces.model.DataProvider to provide data to the ExtendedTableDataModel.

```
ArrayList<XXX> values = ...;
XXXDataProvider xxxDataProvider = new XXXDataProvider(values);
ExtendedTableDataModel<XXX> xxxDataModel = new ExtendedTableDataModel<XXX>(xxxDataProvider);
```

The selection is binding to

```
/** Binding selection */
private SimpleSelection xxxSelection;
```

Last, to retrieve the selected object from your dataprovider :

```
key = xxxSelection.getKeys().next();
selectedObject = xxxDataModel.getObjectByKey(key);
```